# I am working on converting an XML file to CSV using C#. I have tried different approaches but cannot figure out how to access the key name/value pairs

Tags: c#, xml

This is the basic file layout.

```
<InvoiceNo>1065178</InvoiceNo>
<InstallationId>10903</InstallationId>
<CreateDate>2019-03-29T00:00:00</CreateDate>
<AccountNo>123456</AccountNo>
<BalanceDue>1024.40</BalanceDue>
<StatementDate>2019-04-01T00:00:00</StatementDate>
<NoPrint>0</NoPrint>
<Pages>
<Page templatepage="1">
<OtherFields>
<Key name="Instructions1"><Value>Please write your account number on your check!</Value></Key>
<Key name="AgeTitle1"><Value>CURRENT </Value></Key>
<Key name="AgeTitle2"><Value>30 DAYS </Value></Key>
<Key name="AgeTitle3"><Value>60 DAYS </Value></Key>
<Key name="AgeTitle4"><Value>90 DAYS </Value></Key>
</OtherFields>
</Page>
</Pages>
</Invoice>
```

I can get the top level, Invoice No, Create Date but haven't been able to get to the key name/value pairs where most of the data is. Here is my latest try to get it loaded into a dictionary, it loads the entire  node into one entry and i need to get it seperated. I am not invested in using the dictionary, it is simply my latest attempt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
string xmlfile = @"C:/data//WDM/CUSTInvoiceData2019032902.xml";
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(xmlfile);


XmlNodeList nodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='OtherFields']");
Dictionary<string, string> dictXml = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
{
    foreach (XmlNode elementpair in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        dictXml.Add(elementpair.Attributes["Key name"].Value, 
        elementpair.Attributes["value"].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: what if an invoice has multiple pages?

Comment: Let me guess: there are many Invoice nodes in XML? And show what the final CSV should look like.

Comment: There is a footer key that marks the next page as Continued and that will a new line in the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xml Serialization

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
       const string FILE = @"c:\TEMP\TEST.XML";
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILE);
           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice));
           Invoice invoice = (Invoice)serializer.Deserialize(reader);


        }
    }
    public class Invoice
    {
        public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
        public string InstallationId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }
        public decimal BalanceDue { get; set; }
        public DateTime StatementDate { get; set; }
        public int NoPrint { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Pages")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Page")]
        public Page[] pages { get; set; }

    }
    public class Page
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int templatepage { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("OtherFields")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Key")]
        public Key[] keys { get; set; }
    }
    public class Key
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Value  Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Value
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Trying this and i am able to get to the Top level items invoice.InvoiceNo for example but i haven't been able to access the OtherFields array?

Comment: I added image above.  All Id did was to add at beginning of the XML the missing root tag<Invoice>

Answer (score 0):

Almost done

1. You fail on attribute name not `.Attributes["Key name"]` but `.Attributes["name"]`
2. You must get the value and not the attribute, also you must get the child note value

```
    foreach (XmlNode elementpair in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        var key = elementpair.Attributes["name"].Value;
        var val = elementpair.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Value;
        dictXml.Add(key,val);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this and it was looking good until i ran into an empty value and found out i can't have a NULL in the dictionary without creating a custom dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the `Key` elements and looking for two attributes: `Key name` and `value`. But the elements don't have attributes with those names. The key is in an attribute called `name`, and the corresponding value is in a child element (not an attribute) called `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

In your file layout you forgot to add `<Invoice>` at the start.

And this is a simpler way of doing the query. `"//Key"`

```cs
XmlNodeList nodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//Key");
Dictionary<string, string> dictXml = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
    dictXml[node.Attributes[0].Value] = node.InnerText;
```